# How to Set/Insert text/value in Excel using Apache Poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

This method will take a String value for the name to search and return the address for the first record found in the column next to it, assuming that the name is in the first column and the address is in the second column. It will iterate over all sheets as asked. How can i change/enhance this code to Insert/Set value/Text in the third column?

```
public static String findAddressByName(String nameToSearch) {
        String fileLocation = "I:\\foo.xlsx";
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(new File(fileLocation));
        for (int sheetIndex = 0; sheetIndex < wb.getNumberOfSheets(); sheetIndex++) {
            XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(sheetIndex);
            for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < sheet.getLastRowNum(); rowIndex++) {
                XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(rowIndex);
                if (row != null && row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue().equals(nameToSearch)) {
                    return row.getCell(1).getRawValue();
                }
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Comment: Please see this link, it has information on how to add data to the sheets in the excel sheet.
https://www.mkyong.com/java/apache-poi-reading-and-writing-excel-file-in-java/

Comment: And also here : https://www.callicoder.com/java-read-excel-file-apache-poi/

Comment: I have it, but as asked above i need to change the code posted above. Any inputs on that?